# Add the action of Parallel.For to List<Task>

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

What I'm trying to achieve is something like below

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
Parallel.For(1, 5, async (x) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} begin");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} done");
    tasks.Add(this_async_action_itself);
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I thought `tasks.Add(this);` may work but it doesn't.

I knew I can do alternatives like

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}
var tasks = list.Select(async item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {item} begin");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {item} done");
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or in a higher level framework, I can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` perhaps.

I just figure this should be doable and want to know the syntax.

Comment: Why do you mixing async Task with CPU bound Parallel ?

Comment: @eocron This is just an example code not the actual usage

Comment: The `List<T>` is not thread-safe, so the `tasks.Add(this_async_action_itself)` inside the parallel loop is undefined behavior. It's not clear what you want to do, and what you mean with *"may work"*. Could you include in the question what is the expected/desirable behavior of your code, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should know is `Parallel` is already asynchronously executing the actions:

```
var result = Parallel.For(1, 5, x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} begin");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} done");
});
Console.WriteLine(result.IsCompleted);
```

Then to answer your question, there is no `this_async_action_itself` inside a lambda expression, the `Task` object is the return value of the lambda expression:

```
Parallel.For(1, 5, y =>
{
    static async Task foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} begin");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        Console.WriteLine($"blob {x} done");
    };
    tasks.Add(foo(y));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, parallelism is mostly useful for CPU bound operations, while async is more useful for IO operations. I would try to avoid mixing the concepts, since you run some risk of choking whatever IO device you are using.

That said, you might consider using dataflow, most blocks seem to have a constructor that can take either an asynchronous or synchronous method, and you can configure the degree of parallelism:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
    MyAsyncMethod,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 });
block.Post(1);
block.Post(2);
block.Post(3);
block.Complete();
block.Completion.Wait();
```

The main advantage of using dataflow would however be the ability to connect blocks in a pipeline.

Comment: A gotcha of TPL Dataflow is that in case the `MyAsyncMethod` is canceled, the cancellation is not propagated as an error or otherwise. It is [silently ignored](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619 "Dataflow TransformBlock silently fails if TaskCanceledException is thrown").